# violation of primary key error in identity column sql server 2016 enterprise edition sp1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

We have a table called `[URCIPRO].[ACTLOGSLNO_Seq`,this table is having only two columns

```
(1) SeqID <IDENTITY DECIMAL(18,0)>  
(2) SeqVal <BIT>.
```

This table used to generate the log table serial number, so it will have frequent and multiple hit at same time.

> Issue: we are getting primary key violation error frequently for this above table even though its IDENTITY KEY.

Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: please post your create-table script so we can see the table definition

Comment: similar issue was there in 2012 and got fixed. You can check there for more etails https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122254/sudden-primary-key-violation-on-identity-column

Comment: Please find the Table script
CREATE TABLE [URCIPRO].[ACTLOGSLNO_Seq](
 [SeqID] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [SeqVal] [bit] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [SeqID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: Please, all edits go into question, not into comments. Also provide SQL statements, giving error - table structure itself doesn't produce errors.

Comment: The value is auto generated by SQL, we have the same inserts in SQL 2014 and we don't face issue in sql 2014,  only in sql 2016 we are facing these kind of errors

Error Message
                                                               i.      {"ErrorCount":1,"JSonResult":null,"ErrorHandle":[{"ErrorNo":null,"ErrorMessage":"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ACTLOGSL__7AF8B18757A8C4B5'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'URCIPRO.ACTLOGSLNO_Seq'. The duplicate key value is (13587962).\nThe statement has been terminated.","IsException":false,"Action":0,"IsWrite":false}]}